# Why html not showing in the email i sent using php mail() function?

Tags: php, html, email

I sent email confirmation massage using php mail() function but it's not processing html tags . have any idea why?

```
   $content="Dear $name, <br /><br />Thank you for registering at NAME. Before we can activate your account one last step must be taken to confirm your email address .";
            $content.="<br /><br />Please note - you must complete this last step. You will only need to visit this URL once to confirm your email address.<br /><br />To complete your registration,";
            $content.=" please visit this URL:<br /><a href='$link1' target='_blank'> $link1 </a><br /><br /><br />";
            $content.="If you are still having problems signing up please contact a member of our support staff at&nbsp;<a href='mailto:email@gmail.com'>email</a> or contact our <a href='$link2'>customer care</a>. <br /><br />";
            $content.="All the best,<br />NAME<br />";
            mail($custArray['email'],"Please Confirm Your Email",$content);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#example-3141

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify in the header that this is an html email so it will be interpreted as html rather than plain text.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$content="Dear $name, <br /><br />Thank you for registering at NAME. Before we can activate your account one last step must be taken to confirm your email address .";
$content.="<br /><br />Please note - you must complete this last step. You will only need to visit this URL once to confirm your email address.<br /><br />To complete your registration,";
$content.=" please visit this URL:<br /><a href='$link1' target='_blank'> $link1 </a><br /><br /><br />";
$content.="If you are still having problems signing up please contact a member of our support staff at&nbsp;<a href='mailto:email@gmail.com'>email</a> or contact our <a href='$link2'>customer care</a>. <br /><br />";
$content.="All the best,<br />NAME<br />";
mail($custArray['email'],"Please Confirm Your Email",$content, $headers);
```

Comment: i did try that too. sorry for not including that in my code . here is what i put `$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0rn"; $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1rn"; $headers .= "From: NAME\r\n";` but no luck.

Comment: $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1rn"; is missing the backslashes... \r\n

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to add the headers for an html email. Here is the example from the php website ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: i did try that too. sorry for not including that in my code . here is what i put `$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0rn"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1rn"; 
    $headers  .= "From: NAME\r\n";` but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using an external library to handle HTML email. I've used http://swiftmailer.org/ successfully in the past.

Answer (score 0):

```
$headers  = "From: $email\r\n" . "Reply-To: $email\r\n" . "CC: $cc\r\n";

$message  = "$logmsg \r\n\n";
$message .= "Name : $name \r\n\n";
$message .= "Email : $email \r\n\n";
$message .= "Phone No : $phone \r\n\n";
```